# parsing date from string, nsdate, objective c

Tags: objective-c, nsdate, nsdateformatter

Below is a string represented a date

```
NSString *dateStr = @"2011-07-06";
```

And when I am trying to convert it to *NSDate* by doing :

```
    NSDateFormatter *format         =   [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];

    [format setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd"];
    NSDate      *tmp                =   [format dateFromString:dateStr];
    NSLog(@"tmp  is %@",[tmp description]);
```

What I am getting from the console is

```
tmp  is 2011-07-06 04:00:00 +0000
```

I dont understand why I am getting extra info :`04:00:00 +0000` for the result

Please help if you experienced it before

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code

```
NSString *dateStr = @"2011-07-06";
NSDateFormatter *format         =   [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];

[format setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd"];
NSDate      *tmp                =   [format dateFromString:dateStr]
```

will result in a NSDate object, that represents your local time at 0:00 — the beginning of the day.

but if you print a plain date object, it will result in a string that represents the time in GMT timezone, as internally all dates are normalized to that timezone.

As your string is 4 hours ahead, we can tell, that you most likely are in East Europe, maybe Moscow.

So if you want to see the string in your timezone, you need to use a NSDateFormatter to create it from the date object.

```
NSLog(@"tmp  is %@",[formatter stringFromDate:tmp]);
```

to check, if it is correct, what I said,  change the format to contain the time components.

```
formatter.format = [@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm"];
NSLog(@"tmp  is %@",[formatter stringFromDate:tmp]);
```

The formatter will also take "oddities" like Leap Day, [Leap Month](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hebrew_calendar#Leap_months) (yes — those exits), Daylight Saving Times, [Leap Seconds](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leap_second) … in account — accordantly to the current calendar.

---

A great WWDC 2011 Video: [Performing Calendar Calculations](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2011/?id=117) — a must-see for every cocoa developer.

---

BTW: to print a object with NSLog you dont need to call `-description` on it to pass in a string. NSLog will do this internally.

```
NSLog(@"tmp  is %@", tmp);
```

is just fine.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is simple, `NSLog` just converts the `NSDate` to a `NSString`, using its formatter with GMT (zero) timezone.

Your formatter is by default set to your default time zone, which is probably `-4:00`. When you print it out, `NSLog` converts it to `0:00`, adding 4 hours.

In general, it's unsafe to parse dates without specifying their timezone.